# PageSpeed Insights screenshot-thumbnails audit Showing Only three screenshot thumbnails

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using lighthouse for creating performance reports for my own websites. But it showing only three screenshot, While Performancescore is 82 and Accessibility,Best Practices,SEO score are 100.
Website url is https://www.mobilenumbertracker.in/

Here are screen shots :
[image]

[image]

Please help me to point out what is the reason.